# Can't decompress data; zlib not available

Tags: 12.04, python

I already have Python2.7 but due to certain reasons I need to install Python2.4. So, I installed python2.4 and when I run ez_setup.py with Python2.4/python ez_setup.py, I got the error that says

> can't decompress data; zlib not available.

I installed zlib1g and zlib1g-dev as well. I restarted my console but I am still getting this error. Can anyone help me with this? I got ez_setup.py from this [link](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py).

When I do

> which zlib

in the console it says

> zlib not found

Comment: A little more context on the error might be helpful... Was there more to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't find a Python 2.4 package for Ubuntu, so I assume you tried to compile it from source. If so, you would have had to explicitly configure and compile it with zlib support.

I found a blog article on how to do this here:

http://www.1stbyte.com/2005/06/26/configure-and-compile-python-with-zlib/

basically install zlib1g-dev, and then configure Python with

```
./configure --with-zlib=/usr/include
```

then you can do "make" to generate the Python 2.4 binaries.

Comment: configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-zlib (Python 2.7.3) ??

Comment: run `./configure --help` to see the available options for the software you're trying to build. BTW, if it's Python 2.7, that's widely available as a package for Ubuntu so you shouldn't need to build from source.

Comment: from what directory do you run `./configure --with-zlib=/usr/include`