# Trouble with zip support in custom Python build: zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

Tags: software-installation, pip

I looked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173829/cant-decompress-data-zlib-not-available) but I am not getting a lot out of the answer:

A big reason for this is because I am a new Linux user and I haven't seen all the commands in action yet. I have the exact same problem as [this guy](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1919) but all the responses are too advanced for me right now to understand what exactly it is I need to do.

I am using Linux Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to generate a genesis block to play around with Ethereum and smart contracts. I'm following [this tutorial](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/07/27/final-steps/) and when I'm at the point of putting this in my console:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

I get this error:

```
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

It is my understanding that this has to do with Python not being built with zip support. This may well be the case as I had no idea what I was doing when trying to install Python. What I have done to try and resolve this is to install the latest version of zlib and try it again, but when I tried it again, I still got the same error. I re-installed Python, and I'm still getting the same error. Now, I'm just getting annoyed. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem installing pip: pip command not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793233/problem-installing-pip-pip-command-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you built your Python yourself and not using the default installation. You need to do these steps:

1. Install the `zlib` the newest version
2. Then complie python again and run a line

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/root/Python-2.7.8 --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/lib
   ```

Comment: I guess I need help with compiling a new version of python. Actually, this is an answer that you copy + pasted directly from one of the links that I put in my question. I tried re-installing python and installing the newest version of zlib, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: actually it was answered by pip developer in this link


https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1919

Comment: Which is the exact same link I posted. (Check second link)

Comment: can you send me the respone to `which zlib` and  `which python` ?

Comment: zlib version 1.2.8 and python 2.7.1

Comment: I meant the path of installation. Issue `which python` in your command line and see the results. also the same for zlib

Comment: When I do which python, I get: 
     /usr/local/bin/python
When I do which zlib, I get nothing.

Comment: looks like you `zlib` is installed but python is looking in the wrong directory for it. if `import zlib` in python raises an error, you should follow this guy's script and make a symbolic link for it. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106549/no-module-zlib-for-python-2-6

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

1. edit the file `Modules/Setup.dist`
2. find this

   ```
   #zlib zlibmodule.c -I$(prefix)/include -L$(exec_prefix)/lib -lz
   ```
3. unmask `#`
4. try again!