# Problem installing pip: pip command not found

Tags: command-line, software-installation, pip

Having problems installing pip and not sure why can someone help me find out why the pip is returning `-bash: pip: command not found`?

```
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

$ sudo easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 8.1.2
Processing pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg
pip 8.1.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/pip'
```

Comment: The directory `/usr/local/bin/pip` muat exist before you run the script.  Please read the error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` as it tells you what the problem is....

Answer (score 9):

Install `pip` for Python 2 by running

```
sudo apt install python-pip  # pip for Python 2
```

and for Python 3 by running

```
sudo apt install python3-pip  # pip for Python 3
```

I would discourage you from using `easy_install` at all if possible; to learn more, see the many great answers at https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220404/486919. Also note that the [installation instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) in the official pip documentation does not mention using `easy_install` at all to install `pip`.