# Problem in installing pip in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, pip

Actually, I wanted to install **pip** because I needed to install **pycurl** which was needed for using **Wfuzz**. The main fact is that I need to install pip.

I remembered that I had already installed pip once but since I was getting some kind of weird errors, I just removed pip using

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip
```

But now, when I am using

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

The pip V 8.1 is getting installed, but when I am trying to use it, the error shows.

```
bash: /home/coder/.local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

I already went through this: [Problem installing pip: pip command not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793233/problem-installing-pip-pip-command-not-found)

But there are already 3 pip files at that location, named pip, pip2 and pip2.7

So what should I do now? Any help will be much appreciated as I really need to use the tool wfuzz for other purposes.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279207/installing-pip-using-easy-install?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Dadep. That problem seems different though I tried purging and reinstalling yet no success

Comment: Did you try to install with `yum` or like this : https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ ?

Comment: Hey I was able to install it. I think I just closed and opened my terminal again. Thanks for the help too. But now I am having problems with installing pycurl using the command >pip install pycurl. But its giving some error

Comment: just open new question, for `pycurl` installation if you need help

Comment: Everything worked out for me. I got the same error question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669428/error-in-installation-pycurl-7-19-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had a similar problem a while ago. If I remember correctly, it was solved by purging and reinstalling with

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Purge removes configuration files as well as uninstalling the package.

Comment: Then I had to [fix `/usr/bin/pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210269/importerror-cannot-import-name-main-when-running-pip-version-command-in-windo).

Answer (score 1):

Probably pip is hashed at its previous location. To confirm, run `type pip`. The output may be

```
pip is hashed (/home/coder/.local/bin/pip)
```

If yes, run `hash -d pip`. That will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4
```