# Install PycURL in my virtual environment in PyCharm

Tags: software-installation, python3, gcc, pip, pycharm

I am using and PyCharm in Ubuntu 18.04. I am also using Python 3.7 and pip 20.0.2. So far I have not been able to install PycURL in the virtual environment that I created in PyCharm.

I tried:

1. https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/python-pycurl
2. https://pypi.org/project/pycurl/
3. https://www.howtoinstall.me/ubuntu/18-04/python-pycurl/
4. [Problem in installing pip in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034018/problem-in-installing-pip-in-ubuntu-16-04/)
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669428/error-in-installation-pycurl-7-19-0/
6. easy_install pycurl

I got these errors:

- `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1`
- `ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycurl`
- `unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory`
- `error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Please show me the steps to to install PycURL in my virtual environment in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python3-pycurl and python-pycurl are in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install python3-pycurl open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pycurl
```

Next you must configure your PyCharm project to find the python3-pycurl package that you installed. PyCharm does not automatically find your globally installed Python packages unless the project has been configured to find them. To do this select the *Inherit global-site packages* option when you create a new project.

Select *File* -> *New Project* to create a new project. Click the triangle marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot to show the new project's options. In the below screenshot the project is named *plotimage*.

[image]

Then check the *Inherit global-site packages* checkbox and click the  <kbd>Create</kbd>  button in the lower right corner of the Create Project window.

[image]

Now your PyCharm project will be able to use all global-site Python packages.

Comment: Thanks bro, It works :)

Comment: I also posted a similar answer to this one on Stack Overflow.

Comment: oh! that's great