# I can't import numpy in Visual studo code

Tags: python3, visual-studio-code, numpy

I've installed *Numpy* for *python3*, but when i import the package in *Visual Studio Code* i got this message error :
 Import Error: No module named numpy.

I used  `pip3 install numpy` to install it, the installation went very smoothly. and i try it in the terminal, it works very well but when i opend the file in *Visual Studio Code* and i executed it, i got the message error above.

Is there someone who has any idea about the problem?

Comment: Perhaps this isn't what you want but Visual Studio Code recognizes `import numpy` from `sudo apt install python3-numpy` and [PyCharm](https://askubuntu.com/a/1215717/94914) Community edition recognizes `import numpy` from both `pip install` and `apt install`. PyCharm is more full-featured than Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 1):

you have to check that the python version running from VScode is the same as the one running from the terminal (probably you running a different version of python in VScode and you didn't install numpy there) 
Check https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
For more Info